# Adding new variable with no historical data (only incremental new data) to existing regression model

Tags: regression, stata, missing-data, predictor

I have trained a linear regression model on several hundred observations. I have recently begun collecting data on a new predictor variable and would like to retrain the model with data from this new variable.

How can I retrain the regression model to include the new variable and its more limited data? Obviously, the original observations will not have data for the new variable and by default will be coded as '.' (missing values) in STATA when I run the regression. As a result, these observations will be excluded when I run the regression. I would like to keep those observations in the model, however, as I would like the model to include both the original variables and the new variable.

I appreciate any help you can provide in terms of how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you think the new variable is important, the question comes down to what to do with the older data. Assuming you have a good size dataset with the new predictor, you could retain in the data subset containing both, then impute values for the new variable (on the old data set) that will allow you to still get predictions out, but you’ll have to note that those predictions are altered by that choice.

Comment: `help mi` might be a good place to start.